# How to include a dynamically created file in the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, filestream

I have dynamically created a text file in my project location using

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Images\\abc.png";
FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

But am unable to read that file as it is found to be not included in the project. Including manually is the only way? How can we achieve this dynamically?

Comment: Do you want to use the file at runtime?  Or are you extending visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I am reading the file at runtime immediatly after stuffing it.

Answer (score 0):

**In compile time,** I would add this picture to the project and just live with the fact it's going to change in run-time.

**In run-time**, I would parametrise the reading function to accept a path to the file

```
public void ReadFile(string path)
{
    var fs = File.Open(path);
    ...
}
```